# How to make FastCodePatch work in Delphi XE2 Win64 platform?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe2

Unit FastCodePatch.pas works in Win32 platform.  Delphi XE2 supports Win64 platform, any ideas how to make FastCodePatch works in Win64 platform?

```
unit FastcodePatch;

interface

function FastcodeGetAddress(AStub: Pointer): Pointer;
procedure FastcodeAddressPatch(const ASource, ADestination: Pointer);

implementation

uses
  Windows;

type
  PJump = ^TJump;
  TJump = packed record
    OpCode: Byte;
    Distance: Pointer;
  end;

function FastcodeGetAddress(AStub: Pointer): Pointer;
begin
  if PBYTE(AStub)^ = $E8 then
  begin
    Inc(Integer(AStub));
    Result := Pointer(Integer(AStub) + SizeOf(Pointer) + PInteger(AStub)^);
  end
  else
    Result := nil;
end;

procedure FastcodeAddressPatch(const ASource, ADestination: Pointer);
const
  Size = SizeOf(TJump);
var
  NewJump: PJump;
  OldProtect: Cardinal;
begin
  if VirtualProtect(ASource, Size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OldProtect) then
  begin
    NewJump := PJump(ASource);
    NewJump.OpCode := $E9;
    NewJump.Distance := Pointer(Integer(ADestination) - Integer(ASource) - 5);

    FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, ASource, SizeOf(TJump));
    VirtualProtect(ASource, Size, OldProtect, @OldProtect);
  end;
end;

end.
```

The solution provided by Ville Krumlinde doesn't work on 64 bits package.  It works on Standalone .exe application only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code works for both Win32 - Standalone and Package, Win64 - Standalone and Package:

```
type
  TNativeUInt = {$if CompilerVersion < 23}Cardinal{$else}NativeUInt{$ifend};

  PJump = ^TJump;
  TJump = packed record
    OpCode: Byte;
    Distance: integer;
  end;

function GetActualAddr(Proc: Pointer): Pointer;
type
  PAbsoluteIndirectJmp = ^TAbsoluteIndirectJmp;
  TAbsoluteIndirectJmp = packed record
    OpCode: Word;   //$FF25(Jmp, FF /4)
    Addr: Cardinal;
  end;
var J: PAbsoluteIndirectJmp;
begin
  J := PAbsoluteIndirectJmp(Proc);
  if (J.OpCode = $25FF) then
    {$ifdef Win32}Result := PPointer(J.Addr)^{$endif}
    {$ifdef Win64}Result := PPointer(TNativeUInt(Proc) + J.Addr + 6{Instruction Size})^{$endif}
  else
    Result := Proc;
end;

procedure FastcodeAddressPatch(const ASource, ADestination: Pointer);
const
  Size = SizeOf(TJump);
var
  NewJump: PJump;
  OldProtect: Cardinal;
  P: Pointer;
begin
  P := GetActualAddr(ASource);
  if VirtualProtect(P, Size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OldProtect) then
  begin
    NewJump := PJump(P);
    NewJump.OpCode := $E9;
    NewJump.Distance := TNativeUInt(ADestination) - TNativeUInt(P) - Size;

    FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, P, SizeOf(TJump));
    VirtualProtect(P, Size, OldProtect, @OldProtect);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is actually the answer to a different question. Ville answered your original question. Patching functions in packages is a different game. The code you present is needed on 32 bit targets too.

Comment: Great code! I confirm it works perfectly with `Delphi 10.1` (Berlin) under 32/64-bit `Windows 7`, even with `DEP` enabled.

Answer (score 12):

For the FastcodeAddressPatch-function, this version works both in 32-bit and 64-bit when I try. The key is changing "pointer" to "integer" because the Intel relative jump-instruction ($E9) still use an 32-bit offset in 64-bit mode.

```
type
  PJump = ^TJump;
  TJump = packed record
    OpCode: Byte;
    Distance: integer;
  end;

procedure FastcodeAddressPatch(const ASource, ADestination: Pointer);
const
  Size = SizeOf(TJump);
var
  NewJump: PJump;
  OldProtect: Cardinal;
begin
  if VirtualProtect(ASource, Size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OldProtect) then
  begin
    NewJump := PJump(ASource);
    NewJump.OpCode := $E9;
    NewJump.Distance := NativeInt(ADestination) - NativeInt(ASource) - Size;

    FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, ASource, SizeOf(TJump));
    VirtualProtect(ASource, Size, OldProtect, @OldProtect);
  end;
end;

procedure Test;
begin
  MessageBox(0,'Original','',0);
end;

procedure NewTest;
begin
  MessageBox(0,'Patched','',0);
end;

procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FastcodeAddressPatch(@Test,@NewTest);
  Test;
end;
```

I'm not sure what the other function does but I'm guessing it should be like this:

```
function FastcodeGetAddress(AStub: Pointer): Pointer;
begin
  if PBYTE(AStub)^ = $E8 then
  begin
    Inc(NativeInt(AStub));
    Result := Pointer(NativeInt(AStub) + SizeOf(integer) + PInteger(AStub)^);
  end
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

Comment: +1 To be clear the difference is that the version in the question uses an 8 byte pointer in the TJump record which is incorrect.

Comment: Aha, now I want to remove my upvote. `Integer(ADestination) - Integer(ASource)` cannot be correct on Win64. You need to use `NativeInt`.

Comment: @David: Changed to NativeInt in the expression. The Distance-field that is the destination of the expression needs to be 32-bit just like you say.

Comment: There's another spurious Integer cast at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @David: Fixed. It's too easy to forget these things because pointer vs integer casts does not create a compiler warning and also because when I run in debugger all the addresses are within 32-bit range anyway so errors do not appear. I wish there was a checkbox in the Delphi debugger that forced the program to run in >2gb address space to make sure 32->64 bit conversion bugs are triggered.

Comment: There is such a thing, but not in the Delphi debugger. It's called top-down memory allocation and is a Windows setting. Set in the registry. You need to have a LARGEADDRESSAWARE app and 64 bit to make it worthwhile but it's great. You can configure it per app but that's much harder. Only downside I found was that many many virus scanners can't handle that setting. The best I found was Security Essentials.

Comment: @David: I did not know that, I'll keep it in mind. I tried changing the Image Base setting but any value above around $70000000 does not take effect. Presumably because it is stored as a 32-bit value in the pe-file.

Comment: More likely because you aren't setting the LARGEADDRESSAWARE PE flag.

Comment: @Ville, your code works only in standalone .exe.  If my patch code (e.g.: Test and NewTest are keep in package (.bpl).  Load the package will cause problem in Win64 platform.

Comment: @ChauCheeYang: Do you get an error message? Does it work in 32-bit mode with packages? If you have any more information about the problem with packages please add it to your original question.

Comment: @ChauCheeYang: No, the error message isn't "Access Violation". The error message is "Access Violation. (Violation cause) at 0xXXXXXXXX of address 0xXXXXXXXX". **Exact** error messages are important.

Comment: @Ville: I have post my answer that solve the package problem.