# Delphi hook x64

Tags: delphi, 64-bit

Please i use the follwing code  [ [delphi Hook SetClipboardData from user32.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143733/delphi-hook-setclipboarddata-from-user32-dll)  ]  to hook Clipboard in x86 and That worked well , but my issue now is with x64 and i think the problem is with the PUSH and RET values under x64.
Please if i'm correct can someone give me the correct values of PUSH and RET on x64

Comment: Yeah, asm is very different on x64. There must be a more sensible solution but that code is opaque.

Comment: The most obvious thing that jumps out is that on x64 a pointer is 8 bytes, but a DWORD is only 4. `PUSH` and `RET` have the same opcodes on x86 and x64. Whether or not that hooking technique works when you fix your pointer sizes, I don't know. Did you write the code yourself? Do you have a reference for Win32 API hooking on x64?

Comment: See this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7669528/197220

Answer (score 0):

I Think You Should Change

```
cOpen.Push := $68;
```

To

```
cOpen.Push := $E9;
```